# Stuhl und Sessel in Österreich und Deutschland

Tags: regional, austrian

In Österreich ist ein [Stuhl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuhl) eine bequeme Sitzgelegenheit mit Polstern, in Deutschland bezeichnet man damit die einfache Ausführung (in der Küche, zum zusammenklappen etc.).
Der [Sessel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sessel) ist hingegen in Österreich das einfache Sitzmöbel, in Deutschland die gemütliche Variante.

Auch bei Ausdrücken, in denen Stuhl oder Sessel nur Wortbestandteil sind, ist die Verwendung umgekehrt (oder zumindest finden sich entsprechende Treffer):

> Ö: Bürosessel, Klappsessel, Küchensessel
>   D: Bürostuhl, Klappstuhl, Küchenstuhl

Dass in verschiedenen Regionen verschiedene Ausdrücke für dasselbe Ding verwendet werden (Paradeiser – Tomate), ist völlig normal.

Doch wie kommt es dazu, dass die Bedeutungen zweier Ausdrücke genau vertauscht werden?
Also, dass der österreichische Sessel dem deutschen Stuhl entspricht **und** der österreichische Stuhl dem deutschen Sessel?

---

Meine Prämisse, dass die Ausdrücke vertauscht werden, entstammt den jeweiligen deutschen Wikipediaartikeln:

[Stuhl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuhl):

> Ein Stuhl (in Österreich oft Sessel) ist ein in vielen Varianten ausgeführtes Sitzmöbel für (meist) eine Person, das sich in der Regel aus einem Fußgestell, einer einfachen oder gepolsterten Sitzfläche und einer Rückenlehne zusammensetzt und sich von dem einfachen Schemel ohne Lehne und dem gepolsterten Armsessel unterscheidet.

[Sessel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sessel):

> Ein Sessel (lateinisch sessilis ‚festsitzend‘, ‚zum Sitzen geeignet‘) bezeichnet in Deutschland ein bequemes Sitzmöbel für eine Person, das gewöhnlich mit Armlehnen versehen und weich gepolstert ist.
>
> Im österreichischen Sprachgebrauch ist es umgekehrt.
>   Ein Sessel ist ein einfaches Sitzmöbel mit Lehne (z. B. Küchensessel), ein Stuhl ist etwas bequemer (z. B. Lehnstuhl, Schaukelstuhl) und Schemel oder Hocker ist ohne jede Lehne. Davon wird noch der schwerere Fauteuil unterschieden.

Die Tabelle im Artikel über [Möbel (Sitzmöbel)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bel#Sitzm%C3%B6bel), in der die österreichischen, schweizerischen und deutschen Ausdrücke aufgeführt sind, zeigt allerdings keine so eindeutige Zuordnung, nur eine Tendenz dazu.

Comment: Vgl. auch http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r10-f2ab/

Comment: Paprika + Pepperoni sind von Deutschland zu Schweiz auch exakt vertauscht, ich glaube dieses Phänomen ist gar nicht so selten...

Comment: Ich würde ja behaupten, dass im gesprochenen Österreichischen _Stuhl_ ausschließlich das Produkt des Stuhlganges ist (und auch dann nur, wenn man sich gehoben ausdrücken möchte), und _Sessel_ ziemlich alle Sitzmöbel bezeichnet, die keinen spezielleren Namen haben. Aber das trifft ziemlich gut mit den Karten zusammen, die @Loong verlinkt hat: Graz, wo ich herkomme, ist eindeutig Sessel-Gebiet, und Fauteuil schon eher im Verschwinden begriffen.

Comment: Die hier behauptete Prämisse trifft nicht zu. In Österreich werden die Begriffe nicht umgekehrt verwendet. Details stehen in [meiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50438/stuhl-und-sessel-in-Österreich-und-deutschland/50489#50489).

Comment: Der zweite Absatz aus dem Wikipedia-Artikel über Sessel ist falsch. Ich habe diesen Absatz in Wikipedia bereits überarbeitet, er muss nun noch gesichtet und freigeschalten werden.

Comment: Würde noch hinzufügen, dass es auch in Österreich selbst regionale Unterschiede gibt. In Tirol, wo ich lebe, habe ich noch nie jemand hiesigen zu einem Möbel, das in Deutschland als "Stuhl" bezeichnet würde, "Sessel" sagen hören. Das scheint mir eher typisch für Ostösterreich zu sein - kann ich aber nicht belegen.

Comment: Scheibelstuhl: dreibeinig, rund, ohne Lehne, sehr alt
Melkschemel: einbeinig

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ganz so ist es nicht.

In Österreich wird jedes Sitzmöbel, das für nur eine Person bestimmt ist, als *Sessel* bezeichnet. (Eine Ausnahme wird im nächsten Absatz behandelt.) Und zwar unabhängig davon, ob die Sitzfläche hart oder weich ist, und unabhängig davon, ob das Sitzmöbel Armlehnen hat oder nicht. Auch, ob unten Rollen oder Füße dran sind, ist egal. Lediglich eine Rückenlehne wird erwartet wenn man von einem Sessel spricht, sonst ist es nämlich ein Schemel oder ein Hocker.

Eine Teilmenge davon sind jene Einpersonensitzmöbel, die eine gepolsterte Sitzfläche, eine gepolsterte aber unverstellbare Rückenlehne und Armlehnen haben, jedoch keine Rollen, sondern "normal" kurze Füße. So ein Möbelstück heißt in Österreich nicht *»Sessel«*, sondern *»Fauteuil«*. Mit anderen Worten: Ein Fauteuil ist ein Sofa, auf dem nur eine Person Platz hat.

Der Begriff *Sofa* ist in Östereich übrigens auch wenig gebräuchlich, vor allem bei älteren Personen. Der bevorzugte Begriff dafür ist *Couch*. Bei Personen über 70 Jahren sind auch *Diwan* und *Bettbank* noch gängig, letzteres übrigens auch dann, wenn sich das Sofa nicht zu einem Bett ausziehen lässt, den auch auf einer unveränderbaren *Bettbank* kann man schlafen.

Das Wort *»Stuhl«* wird in Österreich meiner Wahrnehmung nach eher selten benutzt, keinesfalls aber, wie vom Fragesteller behauptet als Bezeichnung für eine *»bequeme Sitzgelegenheit mit Polstern«.* Das Wort *Stuhl* ist vielmehr ein wenig benutztes Synonym für *Sessel,* die beiden Wörter sind also im Wesentlichen gleichbedeutend. Vielleicht benutzt man dieses Wort in Österreich auch weniger oft, weil man mit *Stuhl* eher Darmausscheidungen als Sitzmöbel assoziiert.

Man kennt in Österreich aber z.B. den [Herzogstuhl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herzogstuhl), der ist aber aus Stein und eigentlich ein Thron. (Es gibt keinen Herzogsessel)

Die hohen Sitzgelegenheiten für Kleinkinder, die es ihnen ermöglichen, gemeinsam mit Erwachsenen an einem Tisch zu sitzen, sind in Österreich keine Kinder*sessel*, sondern Kinder*stühle.*

Auch der *elektrische Stuhl* wird auch in Österreich nicht zu einem Sessel.

Das Möbelstück mit hoher Sitzlehne, das man oft in Büros sieht, heißt in Österreich sowohl Bürostuhl (eher selten) als auch Bürosessel (bevorzugt). Die Luxusversion davon heißt aber nur Chefsessel. (Einen Chefstuhl gibt es nicht).

Von Klappstühle redet man in Österreich kaum, wir haben Klappsessel. Das liegt aber daran, dass, wie schon oben erwählt, *Sessel* und *Stuhl* Synonyme sind (mit den hier genannten Ausnahmen), und uns Ösis das Wort *Sessel* generell lieber ist.

Comment: Ich hatte die Einträge in der Wikipedia so interpretiert, dass die Ausdrücke vertauscht wären. Siehe mein edit der Frage. Die Tabelle im Artikel über Möbel bestätigt, was du in deiner Antwort über die Verwendung von (öst.) Stuhl als (dt.) Sessel schreibst. Habe die Tabelle dort erst jetzt gesehen.

Comment: Do not trust Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

Im "Austria-Forum" der TU Graz findet sich [ein Beitrag](https://austria-forum.org/af/Wissenssammlungen/%C3%96sterreichisches%20Deutsch/Sessel%20-%20Stuhl), der sich ausführlich mit dieser Fragestellung befasst. Demnach hat sich die Bedeutung der beiden Begriffe "Sessel" und "Stuhl" im Laufe der Jahrhunderte mehrfach geändert und muss wahrscheinlich auch im Kontext der Entwicklung der Sitzgelegenheit (vom einfachen Hocker oder Schemel über Ausstattung mit Rückenlehne und Armlehne bis hin zur Polsterung) gesehen werden:

> Die Bedeutung der Ausdrücke „Sessel“ und „Stuhl“ hat sich im Laufe der Jahrhunderte mehrmals geändert, wobei der Süden des Sprachraums anders reagiert hat als der Norden. So charakterisiert Mitte des 18. Jahrhunderts der an der Wiener Universität lehrende Johann Siegmund Popowisch den Sprachunterschied zwischen Österreichern und Sachsen wie folgt: „Sessel“ ist ein gefütterter Lehnstuhl im Österreichischen (...). Die Sachsen machen hingegen keinen Unterschied zwischen einem gefütterten und einem ungefütterten Stuhl. Sie nennen beide „einen Stuhl“.
>
> Erst Ende des 18. Jahrhunderts kam es in Österreich zu einer Bedeutungsverschiebung, die bis zum heutigen Tag ihre Gültigkeit hat. Bequeme Sessel mit einer Polsterung auf der Sitzfläche und auf der Rückenlehne heißen seit damals in Österreich (vor allem im Osten) „Fauteuil“. Sie haben in der Regel auch eine Armlehne, ähnlich wie ein Sofa.

[...]

> Das Wort „Stuhl“ ist ein wenig älter als das Wort „Sessel“. „Stuhl“ ist schon im Althochdeutschen, und zwar im 8. Jahrhundert als stuol belegt. Das Wort ist eine Ableitung zu „stehen“. Der Ausdruck „Sessel“ ist im Althochdeutschen als sezzal belegt, der älteste Nachweis stammt aus dem 9. Jahrhundert. Das Wort ist eine Ableitung zu „sitzen“, die ursprüngliche Bedeutung war also „Sitz“.

[...]

> „Sessel“ ist also, in dem Sinn, wie es in Österreich heute verwendet wird, ein modernes Wort. Bei der Bedeutungsverschiebung hat einerseits das Aufkommen des neuen Ausdrucks „Fauteuil“ eine Rolle gespielt. Sprachwissenschafter weisen aber auch darauf hin, dass in einigen Mundarten Österreichs das Wort „Stuhl“ auch im Sinn von „Schemel“ (= kleine Bank, Fußbank) verwendet worden ist. Diesfalls ist das Wort „Stuhl“ immer öfter für ein anderes Möbelstück verwendet worden, so dass herkömmliche Stühle als „Sessel“ bezeichnet worden sind.

Comment: Der kleine Fehler in der Schreibung des Namen des Popowi~t~sch in Zusammenhang mit der Unterscheidung von Sessel und Stuhl ist brillant :-)

Answer (score -3):

Mein Sprachgefühl empfindet

**Sessel** als etwas leichtbeiniges, gelsenartiges, hingegen

**Stuhl** als etwas lastendes, schweres, kuhfladiges.

Freilich ist das Wort "Stuhl" in Österreich nicht unbekannt, aber nicht in der Bedeutung "einfache Sitzgelegenheit".

Gehen wir es hierarchisch an: Es gibt den

Heiligen Stuhl, den

Bischofsstuhl, den

Kaiserstuhl, den

Königsstuhl, den

Herzogstuhl, den

Lehrstuhl, den

Dachstuhl, den

Glockenstuhl, den

Webstuhl, und last not least natürlich den

Stuhlgang. (In diesem Sinne verstehe ich auch die Frage nach einem harten oder weichen Stuhl).

Das sind doch keine leichten Sitzgelegenheiten!

Comment: Ich verstehe die Downvotes nicht; schon gar nicht ohne jede Begründung.

Comment: @Olafant, man könnte damit anfangen, dass es die Frage nicht beantwortet.

Comment: @CarstenS Das könnte man. Und wenn man einen neuen Benutzer darauf hinweist, was mit seiner Antwort nicht stimmt, könnte man ihm sogar noch Gelegenheit geben, sie zu verbessern. Immerhin trägt die Antwort zum Thema bei. Das sind doch tatsächlich alles Stühle.

Comment: @Olafant, es steht Dir frei. Dich auf die Fäkalphantasien einzulassen.

Comment: @CarstenS Siehst du ... daher weht nämlich der Wind. Wer einen Kalauer findet, darf ihn behalten.

Comment: @Olafant, hoffen wir nur, dass der Wind nicht aus Richtung dieser "Antwort" weht.

Comment: ... die Frage nicht beantwortet ... 
Die Frage lautet: Stuhl und Sessel in Österreich und Deutschland. Was für eine Frage!